# How to reset my github.io git hub page domain back to its default?

Tags: http, github, ssl, github-pages, web-hosting

A couple years ago I was experimenting with github pages to launch a portfolio site of mine. While doing so, I at one point acquired a domain called `danielforhire.com`. I don't remember how I did so but while attempting to deploy a new portfolio resume project to github pages, it seems that I somehow configured github to point my `user.github.io` domain to `danielforhire.com` as a default. I discovered this because while creating an entirely new node.js vite application, deploying the site shows me that it goes to `danielforhire.com/repo_name`.

The thing is that I don't have this domain anymore. My normal host provider is namecheap so I definitely don't have it anymore. Additionally the domain is for sale so I know with certainty its not configured anywhere on namecheap.

However, I can't figure out how to get my github domain pages to reset to `user.github.io`. I've tried looking everywhere as to how I did it but no luck.

I'm not sure how to go about this process. Does anyone have recommendations that I can try to hunt down this rogue redirection and its root cause? I've made a custom build with my new domain where this currently is not a problem, but I would like to fix this situation though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just go and look for a CNAME file in your portfolio repo.
That file will contain your custom domain details,
So delete that file and commit - push again, This will republish your website back with github.io domain.